# Android OpenGL rendering bug without glClear?

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm developing a drawing application where the user can select a range of brushes and paint on the screen. I'm using textures as brushes and I'm drawing vertexes as points with PointSpriteOES enabled as displayed below.

```
gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
gl.glEnable(GL11.GL_POINT_SPRITE_OES);
gl.glTexEnvf(GL11.GL_POINT_SPRITE_OES, GL11.GL_COORD_REPLACE_OES, GL10.GL_TRUE);
```

The application worked just as desired, but I needed to optimize it for runtime as its framerate dropped under 30 when dealt with a lot of vertexes. Since the application's domain enables it, it seemed a good idea to leave the glClear and leave the redrawing of already existing lines as it's really unnecessary. However, this resulted in a very strange bug I couldn't fix since then. When the OpenGL is not rendering (I have set render mode to `WHEN_DIRTY`), only about 1/3 of all the vertexes are visible on the screen. Requesting a redraw by calling `requestRender()` makes these vertexes disappear and others are shown. There are three states I can tell apart, each state showing an approximate of 1/3 of all vertexes.

I have uploaded three screenshots (http://postimg.org/image/d63tje56l/, http://postimg.org/image/npeds634f/) to make it a bit easier for you to understand. The screenshots show the state where I have drawn three lines with different colors (SO didn't enable me to link all 3 images, but I hope you can imagine it - it has the segments missing from the 1st and the 2nd). It can clearly be seen that if I could merge the screens into a single one, I would get the desired result.

I'm only guessing what the issue is caused by since I'm not an OpenGL expert. My best shot is that OpenGL uses triple buffers and only a single buffer is shown at a given time, while other vertexes are placed on the backbuffers. I have tried forcing all buffers to be rendered as well as trying to force all vertexes to appear on all buffers, but I couldn't manage either.

Could you help me solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your guess is exactly right. The way OpenGL is commonly used, you're expected to draw a complete frame, including an initial clear, every time you're asked to redraw. If you don't do that, behavior is generally undefined. In your case, it certainly looks like triple buffering is used, and your drawing is distributed over 3 separate surfaces.

This model does not work very well for incremental drawing, where drawing a full frame is very expensive. There are a few options you can consider.

### Optimize your drawing

This is not directly a solution, but always something worth thinking about. If you can find a way to make your rendering much more efficient, there might be no need to render incrementally. You're not showing your rendering code, so it's possible that you simply have too many points to get a good framerate.

But in any case, make sure that you use OpenGL efficiently. For example, store your points in VBOs, and update only the parts that change with `glBufferSubData()`.

### Draw to FBO, then blit

This is the most generic and practical solution. Instead of drawing directly to the primary framebuffer, use a Frame Buffer Object (FBO) to render to a texture. You do all of your drawing to this FBO, and copy it to the primary framebuffer when it's time to redraw.

For copying from FBO to the primary framebuffer, you will need a simple pair of vertex/fragment shaders in ES 2.0. In ES 3.0 and later, you can use `glBlitFramebuffer()`.

Pros:

- Works on any device, using only standard ES 2.0 features.
- Easy to implement.

Cons:

- Requires a copy of framebuffer on every redraw.

### Single Buffering

EGL, which is the underlying API to connect OpenGL to the window system in Android, does have attributes to create single buffered surfaces. While single buffered rendering is rarely advisable, your use case is one of the few where it could still be considered.

While the API definition exists, the [documentation](https://www.khronos.org/registry/egl/sdk/docs/man/html/eglCreateWindowSurface.xhtml) specifies support as optional:

> Client APIs may not be able to respect the requested rendering buffer. To determine the actual buffer being rendered to by a context, call eglQueryContext.

I have never tried this myself, so I have no idea how widespread support is, or if it's supported on Android at all. The following sketches how it could be implemented if you want to try it out:

If you derive from `GLSurfaceView` for your OpenGL rendering, you need to provide your own `EGLWindowSurfaceFactory`, which would look something like this:

```
class SingleBufferFactory implements GLSurfaceView.EGLWindowSurfaceFactory {
    public EGLSurface createWindowSurface(EGL10 egl, EGLDisplay display,
                                          EGLConfig config, Object nativeWindow) {
        int[] attribs = {EGL10.EGL_RENDER_BUFFER, EGL10.EGL_SINGLE_BUFFER,
                         EGL10.EGL_NONE};
        return egl.eglCreateWindowSurface(display, config, nativeWindow, attribs);
    }

    public void destroySurface(EGL10 egl, EGLDisplay display, EGLSurface surface) {
        egl.eglDestroySurface(display, surface);
    }
}
```

Then in your `GLSurfaceView` subclass constructor, before calling `setRenderer()`:

```
setEGLWindowSurfaceFactory(new SingleBufferFactory());
```

Pros:

- Can draw directly to primary framebuffer, no need for copies.

Cons:

- May not be supported on some or all devices.
- Single buffered rendering may be inefficient.

### Use EGL_BUFFER_PRESERVE

The EGL API allows you to specify a surface attribute that requests the buffer content to be preserved on `eglSwapBuffers()`. This is not available in the `EGL10` interface, though. You'll have to use the `EGL14` interface, which requires at least API level 17.

To set this, use:

```
EGL14.eglSurfaceAttrib(EGL14.eglGetCurrentDisplay(), EGL14.eglGetCurrentSurface(EGL14.EGL_DRAW),
                       EGL14.EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR, EGL14.EGL_BUFFER_PRESERVED);
```

You should be able to place this in the `onSurfaceCreated()` method of your `GLSurfaceView.Renderer` implementation.

This is supported on some devices, but not on others. You can query if it's supported by querying the `EGL_SURFACE_TYPE` attribute of the config, and check it against the `EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED_BIT` bit. Or you can make this part of your config selection.

Pros:

- Can draw directly to primary framebuffer, no need for copies.
- Can still use double/triple buffered rendering.

Cons:

- Only supported on subset of devices.

### Conclusion

I would probably check for `EGL_BUFFER_PRESERVE` support on the specific device, and use it if it is suppported. Otherwise, go for the FBO and blit approach.