# How to let OpenGL keep objects that already drawn and render new ones?

Tags: opengl

How to let OpenGL keep objects that already drawn and render new ones?

What I want to do is that get position values each time and draw points.

But, what I find is when I try to draw a new point then the last point was gone away.

Do I have to save all the position valuses?

I am afraid that there would be lots of them to keep on the memory.

Is there any other way to do is job? Please help me....

Comment: Here is a similar question where I answered with a few options: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27320613/android-opengl-rendering-bug-without-glclear. Some of them are platform (Android) specific, but part of them are general, or can be adapted for other platforms.

Answer (score 1):

do you know what is the [Magic Screen](https://www.google.com/search?q=toy%20magic%20screen&espv=2&biw=1444&bih=1118&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjkiJiUqrfKAhUY5GMKHQVoCs8Q_AUIBygC)?

OpenGL works like this. You have a what is called a "frame buffer": an area in memory that starts "clean" every draw cycle, just like the Magic Screen... then you draw whatever you want in a frame. Everything you draw on screen does NOT keep any link with the source of information the drawing came from... in other words, when you draw a line in a coordinate (a,b,c,d), that line doesn't keep any information about such coordinate. It's the programmer responsability to keep (a,b,c,d) somewhere else in order to identify that there's a line... OpenGL is only the rendering itself, just the final picture, in this case.

In the next frame, you clean the frame buffer again, just as cleaning the Magic Screen (when you shake it)... and starts rendering again...

PS: of course OpenGL is far bigger than this, this is just a simplified way to answer your question... things like working with 2 frame buffers and swapping them are more efficient, and OpenGL does this. There are also other concepts in scene, like depth buffers for 3D, etc... but I think my comparison to the Magic Screen is enough to answer you question.